# Identify transaction with default value table SQLServer

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions, default-value, sql-function

I have a table where I do only INSERT operations.

I'd like to uniquely identify these transactio operations through a unique default value (I could do some sequentially INSERT in a transaction that i want to identify with a same id).
Example:

```
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO Table_Example (Id, Value)
VALUES (1,'TEST'), (2,'TEST 2'), (3,'TEST 3)

INSERT INTO Table_Example (Id, Value)
VALUES (4,'TEST 4'), (5,'TEST 5'), (6,'TEST 6)

END
```

Result in Table_Example (Session_Id has been set as i'd like to do)

```
Id |    Value     | Session_Id
1       TEST        sakmfnsakjnfms-jkfhsajfs-1
...
6       TEST 6      sakmfnsakjnfms-jkfhsajfs-1
```

this can be accomplished through such a function or is there any best practices?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265386/current-transaction-id-in-an-audit-trigger

Comment: there is a possibility to keep (SELECT transaction_id FROM sys.dm_tran_current_transaction) as default value of column?