# Is there a way to get trigger id in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I am using trigger after update , I created table to store the changes, I want record also the reason behind change , so when ever the trigger fires I want to update that specific record , is there a way to get that 'transaction ID' to be used when updating.
like ..
Update tblAudit set reason = 'some reason' where ??

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work on SQL Server 2016 or later

Use `SELECT CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID()`