# How to implement Auditing/versioning of Table Modifications on PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, versioning, audit, database-versioning

We're implementing a New system using Java/Spring/Hibernate on PostgreSQL. This system needs to make a copy of Every Record as soon as a modification/deletion is done on the record(s) in the Tables(s). Later, the Audit Table(s) will be queried by Reports to display the data to the users.

I was planning to implement this auditing/versioning feature by having a trigger on the table(s) which would make a copy of the modified row(deleted row) "TO" a TABLE called ENTITY_VERSIONS which would have about 20 columns called col1, col2, col3, col4, etc which would store the columns from the above Table(s); **However, the problem is that** if there is more than 1 Table to be versioned and ONLY 1 TARGET table(ENTITY_VERSIONS) to store all the tables' versions, how do I design the TARGET table ?

OR is it better that there will be a COPY of the VERSION Table for each Table that needs versioning ?

It will be bonus if some pointers towards PostgreSQL Triggers (and associated Stored Procedure ) code for implementing the auditing/versioning can be shared.

P.S : I looked at [Suggestions for implementing audit tables in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823/suggestions-for-implementing-audit-tables-in-sql-server) and kinda like the answer except I would NOT know what type should OldValue and NewValue be ?

P.P.S : If the Tables use SOFT DELETEs (phantom deletes) instead of HARD deletes, do any of your advice change ?

Answer (score 4):

I would have a copy of each table to hold the versions of that table you wish to keep.  It sounds like a bit of a nightmare to maintain and use a global versioning table.

[This link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) in the Postgres documentation shows some audit trigger examples in Postgres.

Comment: +1
thanks.
I wonder what the strengths of having a "GLOBAL audit TABLE" vs "Audit Table for each Table" are w.r.t querying the data for reporting ?

Comment: If you somehow manage to have a GLOBAL audit table, I foresee ALOT of type casting.  I mean...what type would you store all the columns in?

Answer (score 2):

In global table all columns can be stored in single column as hstore type.  I just tried audit and I it is works great, I recommend it.  Awesome audit table example tracks all changes in single table by simply adding a trigger onto the tables you want to begin to keep audit history on.  all changes are stored in as hstore type- works for v 9.1+
  [this link](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus)